# password change field not shown for one user - Ez publish

Tags: php, content-management-system, ezpublish

Hi i am using **Ezpublish** , I logged into the admin panel , and I can search for a user and change his/her password

but for one user i can not change the password , even the password change fields are not shown , I can not figure out the problem actually .

is there any table in **Ezpublish** database where user permissions , access levels stored ???

i checked in

**ezuser

ezuser_accountkey

 ezuser_discountrule
ezuser_role 
ezuser_setting

ezuservisit**

but I could not find a major difference between the 2 users (password can be edited and password can not be edited)

Answer (score 1):

eZPublish stores permissions in 3 tables : `ezpolicy`, `ezpolicy_limitation` and `ezpolicy_limitation_value`.

Maybe an error has been added in `var/log/error.log`

You can enable debug to search in which template the issue appears.